# jQuery datetime picker with date restrictions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

We need a datetime picker that should be configurable to restrict the choice of certain dates (in the past, for example). Optionally it should restrict hours in the past.

Note that we've tried a lot of datetime picker components but they didn't have the restriction option. Note also that [this plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) has `minDate`, but it does not support time picking.

Also, it should be fairly new - i.e. working on 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at **Zebra_Datepicker**, [a highly configurable datepicker jQuery plugin](http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/) which offers a very intuitive mechanism for disabling dates and date ranges using a syntax similar to **cron**‘s syntax, and also makes it easy to make past-only or future-only date pickers.

```
// future-only, starting tomorrow
$('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: 1    
});

// past-only, ending today
$('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: false    
});

// future only starting today
// weekends are disabled
$('#datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: true,
  disabled_dates: ['* * * 0,6']    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dtpicker/

if you combine the time field with up/down arrows there with the jQuery UI datepicker, it might just do the thing for you